# Powershell script real-time monitoring via Windows Service

Tags: powershell

I'm using a script to monitor a file. When a pattern is detected, it will send an email to notify someone.

I am creating a Windows Service via NSSM.

My question is : How can I improve performance of my script ? I have to monitor a large log file during the day. a rolling log file (log1.log, then log2.log, then log3.log etc) main log file
is log.log.
The time between log file rotations in seconds. Rotation time is about 2-3 seconds. Log file size is about 20-30MB.

Script :

```
while( $true ) {

Start-Transcript -path c:\temp\monitor_file.log

$fromaddress = "filemon@contoso.com"
$emailto = "IT@contoso.com"
$SMTPSERVER = "xx.xx.xx.xx"

$File = "C:\temp\log.log"
Get-Content $File -Wait -Last 0 | Select-string  'Finished.' | ForEach {
    Send-mailmessage -from $fromaddress -to $emailto -subject "Log changed" -smtpServer $SMTPSERVER -Encoding UTF8 -Priority High
}

}
```

Comment: How time-sensitive is this ? If you can afford to wait until the log rotates to send your email you could watch for file creation (as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell ) and read the second log (log1.log) ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Get-Content` on a 20-30MB file every 2-3 seconds is very resource intensive, and wasteful if the file only changes a few times a minute. I would follow @anto418's advice, and use a `FilesystemWatcher`.

There are also optimizations you can do within the `FilesystemWatcher`'s event handler to prevent it reading unnecessary data.
You don't want to start from the beginning if you've already read the file several times.

- One option is to set a pointer to the last position you read, and start reading from there whenever there is a change. [Filestream.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=net-7.0) allows you to start at an offset within the file.
- If the 'Finished.' line is always one of the last few lines written, you can optimize further by using the `-Tail` parameter to [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.3): `Get-Content $File -Tail 2`
  This may have been your intent with the `-last 0` parameter, but `-last` doesn't seem to be supported.

I've heard the `-Wait` parameter can lock a file so you miss changes or interfere with writing to it. It's worth testing that this actually works, or removing that parameter.